# Yii: use getIsGuest() or isGuest

Tags: php, authentication, methods, yii

So far, when I wanted to know if the user is logged in or not I used `Yii::app()->user->isGuest`.

However, there is a method called `getIsGuest()`, which returns the `isGuest` variable.

```
if (!Yii::app()->user->getIsGuest())
```

My question is, should I use `getIsGuest()` instead? Using `getIsGuest()` is the proper way? Or it does not matter and they both correct ways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, there is no difference between `$class->getAttribute()` and `$class->attribute`. But this is good to know what is going on in behind.

Yii widely uses php magic methods. In this case, it uses __set and __get magic methods to implement getters and setters. As php's official documents defines `__get()` :

> __get() is utilized for reading data from inaccessible properties.

Consider an example:

```
class Test{
    private $attribute;
    private $attribute2;
    private $attribute3;
    public function getAttribute(){
        return $this->attribute;
    }
    public function getAttribute2(){
        return $this->attribute2;
    }
    public function getAttribute3(){
        return $this->attribute3;
    }
}
```

If you want to get the `attribute` property value you must call `getAttribute()` method and you can not get `attribute` like below (since you have no access to `attribute` property):

```
$test=new Test();
echo $test->attribute;
```

But with __get magic method it can be implemented as:

```
class Test{
    private $attribute;
    private $attribute2;
    private $attribute3;
    //__GET MAGIC METHOD
    public function __get($name)
    {
        $getter='get'.$name;
        if(method_exists($this,$getter))
        return $this->$getter();
    }

    public function getAttribute(){
        return $this->attribute;
    }
    public function getAttribute2(){
        return $this->attribute2;
    }
    public function getAttribute3(){
        return $this->attribute3;
    }
}
```

Now, you are able to get `attribute` value like below:

```
$test=new Test();
echo $test->attribute;
```

To find more about php's magic methods take a look at the php's official document:

[Magic Methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter. If you call `user->isGuest` the method `user->getIsGuest()` gets internally called. It's just kind of an alias.

Comment: I read the source file and couldn't find any variable or method named isGuest, then how does this work?

Comment: when you call `isGuest`, PHP searches for a public property named `$isGuest` withing the `CWebUser` class, failing to find it, it then looks for a `getter` function/method defined as `get<property-name>()`....in this case `getIsGuest()` and uses its return value